# What's the best Find in File mode for EMACS?

Tags: emacs

What's the best package for finding a string in multiple files in EMACS.  I know about grep and such but I would like something that is a little smoother to operate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you haven't read it already - there's lots of relevant tips over at the EmacsWiki [GrepMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepMode) page.

Comment: Seems like grep mode is the best thing going, I'm just going to have to whip out the elisp to get it where i want i guess ;)

Answer (score 7):

There are three builtin functions for grepping in Emacs: grep, find-grep (or grep-find) and rgrep.

The first two work by letting the user edit the grep command line directly.
I usually use the third, rgrep, from "recursive grep". It's a little friendlier, as it prompts the user for the search parameters (search string, file types and directory) one by one, provides customizable defaults, and it automatically ignores some common files and directories you usually don't want to search, like for example .svn or .o files.

Then, there is [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/), and its interface for Emacs: [ack.el](http://www.rooijan.za.net/?q=ack_el), whose default behavior is similar to rgrep, but can be customized to use the options that ack provides.

Comment: I'm a big fan of rgrep -- it's surprisingly easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Dired mode also lets you do a search through marked files with the `dired-do-search` function.

And `ibuffer` lets you do emacs' generic isearch through a bunch of buffers using the awkward key sequence `M-s a C-s`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I find `dired-mode`helpful, especially when used with either `dired-mark-files-regexp` (**%m**) or `dired-mark-files-containing-regexp` to select what should be searched and then `dired-do-search` (**A**).

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by find a string. As others have mentioned, `grep` is very good at what it does.  I use it all the time, everyday.

But if your "string" is, say, a sequence of words within a sentence (which can be multi-line), then `grep` might not be what you want.

Another tool for searching across multiple files or buffers (or bookmarks) is **Icicles** search. The general idea is that it first parses the files into **search contexts** according to some definition (e.g. a regexp), and then it searches for matches to your current minibuffer input (changing the search hits dynamically as you edit your input).

Whereas `grep` always uses lines as search contexts, with **Icicles** search you are not limited in how you define the contexts to search.  The contexts need not partition (exhaust) the file; they can cover as much or as little of the file text as you want.

Among other possibilities, you can use Emacs *thing-at-point* definitions for various kinds of THING as the search contexts.  For example, you can use command `icicles-search-thing` with `sentence` as the THING type, to use sentences as the search contexts.

Or you can use character-property zones as search contexts: search all zones that are font-locked with a given set of faces, for instance. There are many possibilities.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview